# threeparttable / siunitx - getting columns of equal width

Tags: siunitx, threeparttable

I would like to have a table of 6 columns with the last 5 columns being of equal width. As suggested by multiple users here, I am trying to get threeparttable and siunitx to work together. Judging from the ouput, I believe that I did not correctly understand how to implement this. I would be very glad if you could help me on this one.

Please let me know, should you need any more details. Thank you so much for your help and time!

```
\documentclass[review,authoryear,11pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

    \begin{small}
    \begin{singlespace}
    \begin{center}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \rotatebox{90}{

    \begin{threeparttable}

    \caption{\label{tab:tab_worldbank} tbd}

    \begin{tabular}{l*{5}{S}}

        \toprule
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Country}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[x]{@{}c@{}}Strength of\\Insolvency (0-16)\end{tabular}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[x]{@{}c@{}}Resolving\\Insolvency (rank)\end{tabular}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[x]{@{}c@{}}Recovery\\Rate s(\%)\end{tabular}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[x]{@{}c@{}}Recovery\\Time (years)\end{tabular}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[x]{@{}c@{}}Insolvency\\Cost (\%)\end{tabular}}} \\
        \midrule
        Austria & 11.0  & 20    & 82.8\% & 1.1   & 10.0\% \\
        Belgium & 11.5  & 10    & 89.9\% & 0.9   & 3.5\% \\
        Denmark & 12.0  & 8     & 88.0\% & 1.0   & 4.0\% \\
        Finland & 14.5  & 1     & 90.3\% & 0.9   & 3.5\% \\
        France & 11.0  & 24    & 78.5\% & 1.9   & 9.0\% \\
        Germany & 15.0  & 3     & 84.4\% & 1.2   & 8.0\% \\
        Greece & 12.0  & 52    & 35.6\% & 3.5   & 9.0\% \\
        Ireland & 10.5  & 17    & 87.7\% & 0.4   & 9.0\% \\
        Italy & 13.5  & 25    & 63.9\% & 1.8   & 22.0\% \\
        Luxembourg & 7.0   & 82    & 43.7\% & 2.0   & 14.5\% \\
        Netherlands & 11.5  & 11    & 89.3\% & 1.1   & 3.5\% \\
        Portugal & 14.5  & 7     & 74.2\% & 2.0   & 9.0\% \\
        Spain & 12.0  & 18    & 78.3\% & 1.5   & 11.0\% \\
        Sweden & 12.0  & 19    & 77.9\% & 2.0   & 9.0\% \\
        United Kingdom & 11.0  & 13    & 88.6\% & 1.0   & 6.0\% \\
        \textbf{EU15 average} & \textbf{11.9} & \textbf{21} & \textbf{76.9\%} & \textbf{1.5} & \textbf{8.7\%} \\
              &       &       &       &       &  \\
        Brazil & 13.0  & 67    & 15.8\% & 4.0   & 12.0\% \\
        China & 11.5  & 53    & 36.9\% & 1.7   & 22.0\% \\
        India & 6.0   & 136   & 26.0\% & 4.3   & 9.0\% \\
        Russia & 11.5  & 51    & 38.6\% & 2.0   & 9.0\% \\
        \textbf{BRIC average} & \textbf{10.5} & \textbf{77} & \textbf{29.3\%} & \textbf{3.0} & \textbf{13.0\%} \\
              &       &       &       &       &  \\
        United States of America & 15.0  & 5     & 78.6\% & 1.5   & 10.0\% \\
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}%



    \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]\labelsep.0em
    \item tbd
    \end{tablenotes}

    \end{threeparttable}

    }
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \end{center}
    \end{singlespace}
    \end{small}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**edit**
ups, i forgod in half table, which has bold numbers ... now is added

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[authoryear,11pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, threeparttable}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\newcommand\mcc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\thead[b]{#1}}}
\usepackage{siunitx} 

\usepackage{etoolbox} % added

\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont} % <--
\newrobustcmd{\B}{\bfseries}                        % <-- schortcut
    \rotatebox{90}{
    \sisetup{table-column-width=13ex,
             detect-weight}
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Table caption}
    \label{tab:tab_worldbank}
    \begin{tabular}{l S[table-format=2.1]
                      S[table-format=2.0]
                      S[table-format=2.1,table-space-text-post={\,\%}]<{\,\%}
                      S[table-format=1.1]
                      S[table-format=2.1,table-space-text-post={\,\%}]<{\,\%}
                         }
        \toprule
\thead[b]{Country}
    &   {\thead[b]{Strength of\\ Insolvency\\ (0-16)}}
        &   {\thead[b]{Resolving\\ Insolvency\\ (rank)}}
            &   \mcc{Recovery\\ Rate\\ s(\%)}
                &   {\thead[b]{Recovery\\ Time\\ (years)}}
                    &   \mcc{Insolvency\\ Cost\\ (\%)}      \\
        \midrule
Austria         & 11.0  & 20    & 82.8  & 1.1   & 10.0  \cr
Belgium         & 11.5  & 10    & 89.9  & 0.9   &  3.5  \cr
Denmark         & 12.0  & 8     & 88.0  & 1.0   &  4.0  \cr
Finland         & 14.5  & 1     & 90.3  & 0.9   &  3.5  \cr
France          & 11.0  & 24    & 78.5  & 1.9   &  9.0  \cr
Germany         & 15.0  & 3     & 84.4  & 1.2   &  8.0  \cr
Greece          & 12.0  & 52    & 35.6  & 3.5   &  9.0  \cr
Ireland         & 10.5  & 17    & 87.7  & 0.4   &  9.0  \cr
Italy           & 13.5  & 25    & 63.9  & 1.8   & 22.0  \cr
Luxembourg      & 7.0   & 82    & 43.7  & 2.0   & 14.5  \cr
Netherlands     & 11.5  & 11    & 89.3  & 1.1   &  3.5  \cr
Portugal        & 14.5  & 7     & 74.2  & 2.0   &  9.0  \cr
Spain           & 12.0  & 18    & 78.3  & 1.5   & 11.0\ \cr
Sweden          & 12.0  & 19    & 77.9  & 2.0   &  9.0  \cr
United Kingdom  & 11.0  & 13    & 88.6  & 1.0   &  6.0  \cr
\textbf{EU15 average}
&   \B 11.9
    &   \B 21
        &   \B 76.9
            &   \B 1.5
                &      \B 8.7                           \cr
\addlinespace
Brazil          & 13.0  & 67    & 15.8  & 4.0   & 12.0  \cr
China           & 11.5  & 53    & 36.9  & 1.7   & 22.0  \cr
India           & 6.0   & 136   & 26.0  & 4.3   &  9.0  \cr
Russia          & 11.5  & 51    & 38.6  & 2.0   &  9.0  \cr
\textbf{BRIC average}
&   \B 10.5
    &   \B 77
        &   \B 29.3
            &   \B 3.0
                &   \B 13.0                             \cr
\addlinespace
United States of America
                & 15.0  & 5     & 78.6  & 1.5   & 10.0  \cr

    \end{tabular}
    \end{threeparttable}
    }
```

*note:* your *mwe* doesn't work due to missing packages in its preamble. therefore i remove option `review` from `\documentclass` options that table can fit on one page.

maybe solution with use of `sidewaystable` be interesting to you. for it only the following changes in above *mwe* had to be done:

```
...
\usepackage{rotating} % <-- add

\begin{document}

    \begin{sidewaystable} % <---
    \centering
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont} % <--
\newrobustcmd{\B}{\bfseries}                        % <-- schortcut
\sisetup{table-column-width=13ex,
         detect-weight}
    \begin{threeparttable}

 % ... table content

    \end{tabular}
    \end{threeparttable}
    \end{sidewaystable}   % <---
\end{document}
```